# Add Subtotal of count after grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know my question seems familiar, but I'm stuck on this. I am trying to count by group, and I have a query like this:

```
declare @current varchar(4)
set @current = left(dbo.fdatetotext(getdate()),4)

SELECT (Case when GROUPING(NAME) = 0 and
                  GROUPING(CustID) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Name) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Type) =1
             then 'Total ' + NAME
             when GROUPING(NAME) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(CustID) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Name) =1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Type) =1
                  then 'Total'
             ELSE NAME
        END) as Name, 
        CustID, 
        (Case when GROUPING(CNAME) = 0 and
                  GROUPING(CustID) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Name) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Type) =1
            then CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(Distinct Cust_Name ))
            when GROUPING(CNAME) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(CustID) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Name) = 1 and
                  GROUPING(Cust_Type) =1
            then CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(Distinct Cust_Name ))
            ELSE Cust_Name
        END) as Cust_Name, 
        Cust_Type,
        SUM(Case when LEFT(DATE,6) = @current + '01' then Price/1000000 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
        SUM(Case when LEFT(DATE,6) = @current + '02' then Price/1000000 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb'
FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE LEFT(DATE,4) = '2017'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((NAME, CustID, Cust_Name, Cust_Type),
                       (NAME),
                       ()
                      );
```

But the result I am getting is wrong. The sub total shows after the latest data showed, and what I have right now is like this:

[image: table of actual results]

And I want the sub total below after the name. How do I add the subtotal after grouping by name for **Count**? (circle in my img)

e.g: [image: table of wanted results]

Comment: add union for totals then add a sorting calc.. if you can separate your scripts for the details, script to individual totals and script for grand total... then UNION

Comment: What database client are you using?

Comment: @SandPiper sql server bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, jumping straight through your summary table

 Using Union and Group by with name ordering pattern using LEFT function

```
    declare @mytable table ([name] varchar(10),custid int, cust_name varchar(10),custype varchar(5), Jan decimal(8,2), Feb decimal (8,2))

    insert into @mytable
    values 
    ('BoB',1,'AA','X1',1000,2000),
    ('BoB',2,'BB','X5',200,100),
    ('Carl',1,'AA','X1',2000,1000),
    ('Tim',2,'BB','X2',1000,2000),
    ('Tim',3,'BB','X3',2000,1000),
    ('Doom',4,'DD','X4',2000,1000)


declare @mytable table ([name] varchar(10),custid int, cust_name varchar(10),custype varchar(5), Jan decimal(8,2), Feb decimal (8,2))

insert into @mytable
values 
('BoB',1,'AA','X1',1000,2000),
('BoB',2,'BB','X5',200,100),
('Bonnie',2,'BB','X5',200,100),
('Carl',1,'AA','X1',2000,1000),
('Tim',2,'BB','X2',1000,2000),
('Tim',3,'BB','X3',2000,1000),
('Doom',4,'DD','X4',2000,1000)
select name,custid,cust_name,custype,jan,feb from (
   select *,'1' + name nameord from @mytable
   union 
   select 'SubTotal ' + name, null,cast(count(1) as varchar(2)),null,sum(jan) sumofJan, sum(feb) sumofFeb, '1' + name + 'xx'  from @mytable
   group by
   name
   union
   select 'Total ', null,null,null,sum(jan) sumofJan, sum(feb) sumofFeb, '3'  from @mytable
  ) x
  order by x.nameOrd
```

Result

```
name                custid      cust_name  custype jan                                     feb
------------------- ----------- ---------- ------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
BoB                 1           AA         X1      1000.00                                 2000.00
BoB                 2           BB         X5      200.00                                  100.00
SubTotal BoB        NULL        2          NULL    1200.00                                 2100.00
Carl                1           AA         X1      2000.00                                 1000.00
SubTotal Carl       NULL        1          NULL    2000.00                                 1000.00
Doom                4           DD         X4      2000.00                                 1000.00
SubTotal Doom       NULL        1          NULL    2000.00                                 1000.00
Tim                 2           BB         X2      1000.00                                 2000.00
Tim                 3           BB         X3      2000.00                                 1000.00
SubTotal Tim        NULL        2          NULL    3000.00                                 3000.00
Total               NULL        NULL       NULL    8200.00                                 7100.00
```

> Sorting strategy as alpha numeric where detailed starts with 1+name and
>   subtotal with 1+name+xx and Total as 3   or any number after 1

```
nameord       name                custid      cust_name  custype Jan                                     Feb
------------- ------------------- ----------- ---------- ------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1BoB          BoB                 1           AA         X1      1000.00                                 2000.00
1BoB          BoB                 2           BB         X5      200.00                                  100.00
1BoBxx        SubTotal BoB        NULL        2          NULL    1200.00                                 2100.00
1Carl         Carl                1           AA         X1      2000.00                                 1000.00
1Carlxx       SubTotal Carl       NULL        1          NULL    2000.00                                 1000.00
1Doom         Doom                4           DD         X4      2000.00                                 1000.00
1Doomxx       SubTotal Doom       NULL        1          NULL    2000.00                                 1000.00
1Tim          Tim                 2           BB         X2      1000.00                                 2000.00
1Tim          Tim                 3           BB         X3      2000.00                                 1000.00
1Timxx        SubTotal Tim        NULL        2          NULL    3000.00                                 3000.00
3             Total               NULL        NULL       NULL    8400.00                                 7200.00
```

Comment: I edited my question. And what i'm looking for is count of row after grouping by name...

Comment: what is purpose of this statement **'1' + left(name,1)** ,   **'1' + left(name,2)** and **'3'** before @mytable?

Comment: that's your order.. so SubTotal Tim will go after Tim... and 3 will be the total.. sorting as alphanumeric, see explanation above

Comment: updated the script regarding sorting because if Bonnie is inserted